# Extending expression templates for automatic differentiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I am trying to understand expression templates to be able to efficiently evaluate multivariate polynomials like:

```
double PAx,PAy, aAB;
double val = (PAx*PAx*PAx*PAx + 6*PAx*PAX*aAB + 3*aAB*aAB)*(PAy*PAy*PAy*PAy);
```

using expression templates, if possible. How do I modify the following code snippet to achieve this goal?

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct plus;
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct times;

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto operator+(T l, U r){ return plus(l,r);}
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto operator*(T l, U r){ return times(l,r);}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct plus{
    constexpr plus(T1 t1_, T2 t2_):t1{t1_},t2{t2_}{}
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
    template<typename T>
    constexpr auto operator()(T&& t) const {return t1(std::forward<T>(t))+t2(std::forward<T>(t));}
};

template<typename T>
struct is_plus : std::false_type{};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct is_plus<plus<T1, T2>> : std::true_type{};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct times{
    constexpr times(T1 t1_, T2 t2_):t1{t1_},t2{t2_}{}
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
    template<typename T>
    constexpr auto operator()(T&& t) const {return t1(std::forward<T>(t))*t2(std::forward<T>(t));}
};

template<typename T>
struct is_times : std::false_type{};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct is_times<times<T1, T2>> : std::true_type{};

template <typename T, typename U>
using same = std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type,typename std::decay<U>::type>;

int main(){

    constexpr auto x = [](auto t){ return [t](auto t2){return t ;};};
    constexpr auto y = [](auto t){ return [t](auto t2){return t2;};};
    constexpr auto c = [](auto t){ return [t](auto){ return [t](auto){return t;};};};

    constexpr auto zero = [](auto t){ return [t](auto t2){return 0 ;};};
    constexpr auto one = [](auto t){ return [t](auto t2){return 1 ;};};

    constexpr auto recursion = [one, zero, x, y](auto tag, auto t, auto self){
        using t_t = decltype(t);
        using x_t = decltype(x);
        using y_t = decltype(y);
        using tag_t = decltype(tag);
        if constexpr (same<t_t,x_t>::value)
        if constexpr (same<tag_t,x_t>::value)
                return one;
            else
                return zero;
        else if constexpr(same<t_t, y_t>::value)
            if constexpr (same<tag_t,y_t>::value)
                return one;
            else
                return zero;
        else if constexpr( is_plus<typename std::decay<decltype(t)>::type>::value)
            return plus{self(tag, t.t1, self), self(tag, t.t2, self)};
        else if constexpr( is_times<typename std::decay<decltype(t)>::type>::value)
            return plus{times{self(tag, t.t1, self), t.t2}, times{t.t1, self(tag, t.t2, self)}};
        else
            return zero;
    };

    constexpr auto Dx = [recursion,x](auto t){return recursion(x, t, recursion);};
    constexpr auto Dy = [recursion,y](auto t){return recursion(y, t, recursion);};
    // Having defined variables like:
    double PAx,PAy,aAB;
    auto constexpr ex = Dy(x*x*c(4.)+y*x*c(4.)); // I am interested in evaluating expressioons like  (PAx*PAx*PAx*PAx + 6*PAx*PAx*aAB + 3*aAB*aAB)*(PAy*PAy*PAy*PAy)
    auto constexpr val1=ex(5.);
    auto constexpr val=(val1+x(1.))(0.);
    std::cout<<val<<"\n";
    
}
```

The fact that in my application `PAx`, `PAy` and `aAB`, are only known at execution time can have a negative impact on the performance improvement that I am expecting? Can lazy evaluation be preserved?

The snippet is based on this [tutorial](https://github.com/crosetto/AutomaticDifferentiation) I tested the snippet of code  above on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) and [here](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPHV0aWxpdHk%20CiNpbmNsdWRlIDxpb3N0cmVhbT4KdGVtcGxhdGU8dHlwZW5hbWUgVDEsIHR5cGVuYW1lIFQyPgpzdHJ1Y3QgcGx1czsKdGVtcGxhdGU8dHlwZW5hbWUgVDEsIHR5cGVuYW1lIFQyPgpzdHJ1Y3QgdGltZXM7Cgp0ZW1wbGF0ZTx0eXBlbmFtZSBULCB0eXBlbmFtZSBVPgpjb25zdGV4cHIgYXV0byBvcGVyYXRvcisoVCBsLCBVIHIpeyByZXR1cm4gcGx1cyhsLHIpO30KdGVtcGxhdGU8dHlwZW5hbWUgVCwgdHlwZW5hbWUgVT4KY29uc3RleHByIGF1dG8gb3BlcmF0b3IqKFQgbCwgVSByKXsgcmV0dXJuIHRpbWVzKGwscik7fQoKdGVtcGxhdGU8dHlwZW5hbWUgVDEsIHR5cGVuYW1lIFQyPgpzdHJ1Y3QgcGx1c3sKICAgIGNvbnN0ZXhwciBwbHVzKFQxIHQxXywgVDIgdDJfKTp0MXt0MV99LHQye3QyX317fQogICAgVDEgdDE7CiAgICBUMiB0MjsKICAgIHRlbXBsYXRlPHR5cGVuYW1lIFQ%20CiAgICBjb25zdGV4cHIgYXV0byBvcGVyYXRvcigpKFQmJiB0KSBjb25zdCB7cmV0dXJuIHQxKHN0ZDo6Zm9yd2FyZDxUPih0KSkrdDIoc3RkOjpmb3J3YXJkPFQ%20KHQpKTt9Cn07Cgp0ZW1wbGF0ZTx0eXBlbmFtZSBUPgpzdHJ1Y3QgaXNfcGx1cyA6IHN0ZDo6ZmFsc2VfdHlwZXt9OwoKdGVtcGxhdGU8dHlwZW5hbWUgVDEsIHR5cGVuYW1lIFQyPgpzdHJ1Y3QgaXNfcGx1czxwbHVzPFQxLCBUMj4%20IDogc3RkOjp0cnVlX3R5cGV7fTsKCnRlbXBsYXRlPHR5cGVuYW1lIFQxLCB0eXBlbmFtZSBUMj4Kc3RydWN0IHRpbWVzewogICAgY29uc3RleHByIHRpbWVzKFQxIHQxXywgVDIgdDJfKTp0MXt0MV99LHQye3QyX317fQogICAgVDEgdDE7CiAgICBUMiB0MjsKICAgIHRlbXBsYXRlPHR5cGVuYW1lIFQ%20CiAgICBjb25zdGV4cHIgYXV0byBvcGVyYXRvcigpKFQmJiB0KSBjb25zdCB7cmV0dXJuIHQxKHN0ZDo6Zm9yd2FyZDxUPih0KSkqdDIoc3RkOjpmb3J3YXJkPFQ%20KHQpKTt9Cn07Cgp0ZW1wbGF0ZTx0eXBlbmFtZSBUPgpzdHJ1Y3QgaXNfdGltZXMgOiBzdGQ6OmZhbHNlX3R5cGV7fTsKCnRlbXBsYXRlPHR5cGVuYW1lIFQxLCB0eXBlbmFtZSBUMj4Kc3RydWN0IGlzX3RpbWVzPHRpbWVzPFQxLCBUMj4%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%20Ojp2YWx1ZSkKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHJldHVybiBvbmU7CiAgICAgICAgICAgIGVsc2UKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHJldHVybiB6ZXJvOwogICAgICAgIGVsc2UgaWYgY29uc3RleHByKHNhbWU8dF90LCB5X3Q%20Ojp2YWx1ZSkKICAgICAgICAgICAgaWYgY29uc3RleHByIChzYW1lPHRhZ190LHlfdD46OnZhbHVlKQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgcmV0dXJuIG9uZTsKICAgICAgICAgICAgZWxzZQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgcmV0dXJuIHplcm87CiAgICAgICAgZWxzZSBpZiBjb25zdGV4cHIoIGlzX3BsdXM8dHlwZW5hbWUgc3RkOjpkZWNheTxkZWNsdHlwZSh0KT46OnR5cGU%20Ojp2YWx1ZSkKICAgICAgICAgICAgcmV0dXJuIHBsdXN7c2VsZih0YWcsIHQudDEsIHNlbGYpLCBzZWxmKHRhZywgdC50Miwgc2VsZil9OwogICAgICAgIGVsc2UgaWYgY29uc3RleHByKCBpc190aW1lczx0eXBlbmFtZSBzdGQ6OmRlY2F5PGRlY2x0eXBlKHQpPjo6dHlwZT46OnZhbHVlKQogICAgICAgICAgICByZXR1cm4gcGx1c3t0aW1lc3tzZWxmKHRhZywgdC50MSwgc2VsZiksIHQudDJ9LCB0aW1lc3t0LnQxLCBzZWxmKHRhZywgdC50Miwgc2VsZil9fTsKICAgICAgICBlbHNlCiAgICAgICAgICAgIHJldHVybiB6ZXJvOwogICAgfTsKCiAgICBjb25zdGV4cHIgYXV0byBEeCA9IFtyZWN1cnNpb24seF0oYXV0byB0KXtyZXR1cm4gcmVjdXJzaW9uKHgsIHQsIHJlY3Vyc2lvbik7fTsKICAgIGNvbnN0ZXhwciBhdXRvIER5ID0gW3JlY3Vyc2lvbix5XShhdXRvIHQpe3JldHVybiByZWN1cnNpb24oeSwgdCwgcmVjdXJzaW9uKTt9OwogICAgLy8gSGF2aW5nIGRlZmluZWQgdmFyaWFibGVzIGxpa2U6CiAgICBkb3VibGUgUEF4LFBBeSxhQUI7CiAgICBhdXRvIGNvbnN0ZXhwciBleCA9IER5KHgqeCpjKDQuKSt5KngqYyg0LikpOyAvLyBJIGFtIGludGVyZXN0ZWQgaW4gZXZhbHVhdGluZyBleHByZXNzaW9vbnMgbGlrZSAgKFBBeCpQQXgqUEF4KlBBeCArIDYqUEF4KlBBWCphQUIgKyAzKmFBQiphQUIpKihQQXkqUEF5KlBBeSpQQXkpCiAgICBhdXRvIGNvbnN0ZXhwciB2YWwxPWV4KDUuKTsKICAgIGF1dG8gY29uc3RleHByIHZhbD0odmFsMSt4KDEuKSkoMC4pOwogICAgc3RkOjpjb3V0PDx2YWw8PCJcbiI7CiAgICAKfQ==&std=cpp2a&rev=1.0) you can see the instantiation of the templates specializations.

**Update**
Taking into account the suggestions in the comments below, the code was modified as follows:

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

    namespace expr_types {
      template<class D>
      struct formula {
        constexpr auto operator()(auto...args) const {
          return eval(*static_cast<D const*>(this))(args...);
        }
      };
      template<std::size_t I>
      struct var_t:formula<var_t<I>> {
        friend constexpr auto eval( var_t ) {
          return [](auto...args){return std::get<I>( std::make_tuple(args...) );};
        }
      };
      template<std::size_t N>
      constexpr var_t<N> var = {};

      template<class T=double>
      struct val_t:formula<val_t<T>> {
        T k = {};
        constexpr val_t(T in):k(in){}
        friend constexpr auto eval( val_t self ) {
          return [self](auto...){return self.k;};
        }
        friend constexpr auto diff( auto, val_t ) {
          return val_t{0};
        }
      };
      template<class T>
      val_t(T)->val_t<T>;

      template<class Lhs, class Op, class Rhs>
      struct tree:formula<tree<Lhs, Op, Rhs>> {
        Lhs lhs;
        Op op;
        Rhs rhs;
        constexpr tree(Lhs l, Op o, Rhs r):lhs(l),op(o),rhs(r){}
        
        friend constexpr auto eval( tree self ) {
          return eval(self.lhs, self.op, self.rhs);
        }
        friend constexpr auto diff( auto D, tree self ) {
          return diff(D, self.lhs, self.op, self.rhs);
        }
      };
      
      auto operator+( auto lhs, auto rhs ) {
        return tree{lhs, std::plus<>{}, rhs};
      }
      auto operator-( auto lhs, auto rhs ) {
        return tree{lhs, std::minus<>{}, rhs};
      }
      auto operator*( auto lhs, auto rhs ) {
        return tree{lhs, std::multiplies<>{}, rhs};
      }
      auto operator/( auto lhs, auto rhs ) {
        return tree{lhs, std::divides<>{}, rhs};
      }
      struct pow_t {
        auto operator()(auto lhs, auto rhs)const{
          return std::pow(lhs, rhs);
        }
      };
      auto operator^( auto lhs, auto rhs ) {
        return tree{lhs, pow_t{}, rhs};
      }

      // what * means:
      constexpr auto eval( auto lhs, auto op, auto rhs )
      {
        return [=](auto...args){
          // use std::multiplies to avoid seeing above operator*
          return op(eval(lhs)(args...), eval(rhs)(args...));
        };
      }

      // What D(a*b) means:
      constexpr auto diff(auto D, auto lhs, std::multiplies<>, auto rhs) {
        return D(lhs)*rhs + lhs*D(rhs);
      }
      // What D(a/b) means:
      constexpr auto diff(auto D, auto lhs, std::divides<>, auto rhs) {
        return (D(lhs)*rhs - lhs*D(rhs)) / ( rhs^val_t{2} );
      }
      // What D(a+b) means:
      constexpr auto diff(auto D, auto lhs, std::plus<>, auto rhs) {
        return D(lhs)+D(rhs);
      }
      // What D(a-b) means:
      constexpr auto diff(auto D, auto lhs, std::minus<>, auto rhs) {
        return D(lhs)-D(rhs);
      }

      template<class V, class T=double>
      struct differential_t {
        constexpr auto operator()( auto f ) const {
          return diff( *this, f );
        }
      };
      template<std::size_t N, class T, std::size_t M>
      constexpr val_t<T> diff( differential_t<var_t<N>, T>, var_t<M> ) {
        return val_t<T>{N==M};
      }
    }
    namespace expr {
      constexpr auto x = expr_types::var<0>;
      constexpr auto y = expr_types::var<1>;

      constexpr auto val(auto x){
        using namespace expr_types;
        return val_t(x);
      }

      constexpr auto one = val(1);
      constexpr auto zero = val(0);

      template<auto V, class T=double>
      constexpr expr_types::differential_t<decltype(V),T> D = {};
    }

    int main()
    {
      using namespace expr;
      auto f = x*one + x*x + x*x*y + zero;
      std::cout << f(1.0, 2.0) << "\n";
      auto df = D<x>(f);
      std::cout << df(1.0, 2.0) << "\n";
      auto g = (one + x)*(one + y);
      std::cout << g(1.0, 1.0) << "\n";
      std::cout << D<y>(g)(1.0, 1.0) << "\n";
      auto h = (x^val(2));
      std::cout << h(2.0, 2.0) << "\n";
    }
```

Comment: That code looks toxic.  I mean, overriding `operator+` on all types at global scope?  The double if constexpr is awkward; when `tag_t` matches `t_t`, the answer should be `one`.  The zero case is an interesting claim; if you could detect variables, it would be less awkward.  You are being very intrusive in your differentiation code, instead of teaching operators how to be differentiated or distributing it.  And I'm not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, The code is as it was provided in the tutorial I mentioned in the question. If you can make it less toxic? You are welcome to propose a different version with the same functionality that answers the question.

Comment: Sure.  https://godbolt.org/z/v1hKrab6s was fun.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yakk-AdamNevraumont. I am updating the code in the question with your suggestions.

Comment: Anyhow, you can use https://godbolt.org/z/3oxnEWaG7 to see what happens when the argument is runtime or not.  Uncomment `argc=1` and you can see the entire expression evaluates at compile time; comment it, and you see it uses SSE instructions to do the calculations and derivatives, which seems like some decent amount of optimization.  Adding `-ffast-math` can help a lot, because it relaxes strict IEEE compliance and allows reordering that could change rounding.